# Showing $f^{(p)} (0) = f^{(p)} (1)$, with $p=1,2,\cdots$ for $1$-periodic function $f$.

Tags: real-analysis

### Problem

Say we have $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

- $\exists f^{(p)} (0)$, for $p=1,2,\cdots$
- $f(x) = f(x+1), \forall x$.

where $f^{(p)}$ denotes the $p$th derivative of $f$.

> Show $f^{(p)} (0) = f^{(p)} (1)$, with $p=1,2,\cdots$

---

### Try

#### 1) Showing existence of $f^{(p)}(1)$

The only thing guaranteed is the existence of $f^{(p)}(0)$, not $f^{(p)}(1)$. I'm stuck at here.

---

#### 2) Showing $f^{(1)}(0) = f^{(1)}(1)$

Assume $\exists f^{(1)}(1)$. Note that

$$
f^{(1)}(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} = f^{(1)}(1)
$$

---

#### 3) Showing $f^{(p)}(0) = f^{(p)}(1) (p \ge 2)$

Since we have showed $f^{(1)}(0) = f^{(1)}(1)$, **assuming $\exists f^{(2)}(1)$**, we have

$$
f^{(2)}(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{(1)}(h)-f^{(1)}(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{(1)}(1+h)-f^{(1)}(1)}{h} = f^{(2)}(1)
$$

The equalities in higher order (say, $p$) derivatives can be shown as the above, under the assumption that  $\exists f^{(p)}(1)$.

How to prove **1) the existence of $f^{(p)}(1)$**? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In my view, the limit exists means the derivative at the point exist by definition. So there is no assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need some more assumptions, but perhaps they can be inferred from what youve writren. That is not a satisfying answer, but consider this issue; you cannot even write $\frac{f^1(h)-f^1(0)}{h}$, for various h, since you have not stipulated that you know that $f^1(h)$ exists for h in some open set about zero. So, for differentiability of $f^1$ at zero,  you need that function to exist in a neighborhood of 0. So, we have some neighborhood U of zero where $f^1$ exists in order to have a derivative at 0. Values of $f^1$ are computed on that neighborhood via a limit which can be written identically for points in a neighborhood about 1 (shift the neighborhood U the right by 1 without changing the limit via periodicity). So, we must have $f^1(x)$ exists for some neighborhood U of 0 and also on U+1. The exact same argument applies to what I’ve said, replacing $f^1$ with $f^p$.